# Can we use two credentials treatment as same time in zend framwork 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Can we call setCredential() in two times with two setCredentialTreatment() in zend framwork 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

How can you have two credential treatment for the same column. Like if a password field is set credential treatment it can either be md5 or sha1 or something but not the combination of two

Comment: in my database some password has md5 or some in plane text, and it control by another column flag. so how can i implemnt.